# Ruby on Rails Import CSV Error: Illegal quoting in line 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

my models class

```
def self.to_csv
        attributes = %w{a b c d }
        CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
          csv << attributes

          all.each do |script|
            csv << attributes.map{ |attr| script.send(attr) }
          end
        end
      end


      def self.import(file)
          CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, encoding:'iso-8859-1:utf-8') do |row|
          Student.create! row.to_hash
        end
      end
    end
```

For the `def self.import(file)`why I am getting the error I stated in my title: Illegal quoting in line 2. When I change this code `CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, encoding:'iso-8859-1:utf-8')` to `CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true)`  I get different error that says :invalid byte sequence in UTF-8. Why is that. 
 controller class:

```
   def import
      Student.import(params[:file])
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Students imported."
    end
```

Comment: Make sure in your CSV file you don't have smart quotes, and that you have regular quotes. From my experience this error can happen if smart quotes are present.

here is some info on the subject: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html

Comment: Are you sure that the CSV has the expected encoding? How did you check that? How does the second line look like, does it contain any special characters?